# How do I use Chrome or Firefox developer tools console to set cookie data or JSON values that DuckDuckGo gives for settings?

Tags: javascript, json, cookies

I want to use DuckDuckGo for searches but when my cookies reset, I can't easily restore them without redoing all the settings. Their cloudsave does not save data for me. The only hope seems to add in cookies with the developer console.

So DuckDuckGo gives these JSON values and cookie data:

```
{"kp":"-2","kav":"1","kak":"-1","kax":"-1","kaq":"-1","kap":"-1","kao":"-1","kg":"p","kd":"-1","k18":"1","kae":"d","ko":"1","kw":"w"}

p=-2; av=1; ak=-1; ax=-1; aq=-1; ap=-1; ao=-1; g=p; d=-1; 18=1; ae=d; o=1; w=w
```

"document.cookie" requires each value in a separate cookie and "document.cookie = JSON.stringify" doesn't work to save settings either.
I was hoping to have a solution that was quicker than just redoing the settings each time.